# How to make the same method with different parameters take in different inputs in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on some code where I create a website to practice French. I created a method to check my answers but it did not work for a second question. My HTML and JavaScript are below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "Contest.js"></script>
        <title>Verb Practice</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = "button" onclick = "location.href = 'file:///C:/Users/aryan/Desktop/HTML,%20JavaScript,%20&%20CSS/Contest.html#vocab';" value = "Back To Main" />
        <center>
            <h2>Verb Practice</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <p>What is the infinitive for the verb underlined?</p>
                <p>J'<ins>ache&#768;te</ins> une pizza.</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "Q1" value = "" id = "ansGiven"><br>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Answer" id = "Q1" onclick = "getAns('acheter')">
                <p id = "ansRes"></p>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <p>What does the verb <i>attendre</i> mean?</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "Q2" value = "" id = "ansGiven"><br>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Answer" id = "Q2" onclick = "getAns('to wait')">
                <p id = "ansRes"></p>
            </fieldset>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getAns(ans) {
    var ansGiven = document.getElementById("ansGiven").value;
    console.log(ans);
    console.log(ansGiven);

    if (ansGiven === ans) {
        document.getElementById("ansRes").innerHTML = "Correct!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ansRes").innerHTML = "Try Again.";
    }

    ansGiven = "";
}
```

Theoretically, the method getAns() should say whether the input for the given question is correct or wrong. Instead, the first question works fine, but the second question displays its input as nothing. Why would this be happening and what was wrong with the code?

Comment: C'est parce que vous avez dupliqué les ids.

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp):

> An ID should be unique within a page. However, if more than one
>   element with the specified ID exists, the getElementById() method
>   returns the first element in the source code.

To fix that you have to distinguish between your multiple `ansGiven` and `ansRes` too (eg. `ansGiven1`, `ansGiven2`, ...). This will lead to more complicated code and you will probably have to think about it for a while. You can also use the [click event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to find out which element has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have non-unique IDs for some of the DOM elements and the `document.getElementById()` function returns the first element with the given ID.

`ansGiven` and `ansRes` are used two times each. Instead, use unique IDs like `ansGiven-1`, `ansGiven-2`, etc. and `ansRes-1`, `ansRes-2` etc.

You can change the function signature to accept the number of the question as argument:

```
<fieldset>
  <p>What is the infinitive for the verb underlined?</p>
  <p>J'<ins>ache&#768;te</ins> une pizza.</p>
  <input type="text" name="Q1" value="" id="ansGiven-1"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Answer" id="Q1" onclick="getAns('acheter', 1)">
  <p id="ansRes-1"></p>
</fieldset>

function getAns(ans, answerNumber) {
  var ansGiven = document.getElementById("ansGiven-" + answerNumber).value;

  if (ansGiven === ans) {
    document.getElementById("ansRes-" + answerNumber).innerHTML = "Correct!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ansRes-" + answerNumber).innerHTML = "Try Again.";
  }

  ansGiven = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"id" of dom elements must be unique. Your inputs have the same id "ansGiven" and result paragraphs "ansRes". First of all, you have to make them unique. Absolutely not the best method, but since you said you're practicing, give the below code a shot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "Contest.js"></script>
        <title>Verb Practice</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = "button" onclick = "location.href = 'file:///C:/Users/aryan/Desktop/HTML,%20JavaScript,%20&%20CSS/Contest.html#vocab';" value = "Back To Main" />
        <center>
            <h2>Verb Practice</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <p>What is the infinitive for the verb underlined?</p>
                <p>J'<ins>ache&#768;te</ins> une pizza.</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "Q1" value = "" id = "ansGiven1"><br>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Answer" id = "Q1" onclick = "getAns('acheter', 1)">
                <p id = "ansRes1"></p>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <p>What does the verb <i>attendre</i> mean?</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "Q2" value = "" id = "ansGiven2"><br>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Answer" id = "Q2" onclick = "getAns('to wait', 2)">
                <p id = "ansRes2"></p>
            </fieldset>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
function getAns(ans, questionIndex) {
    var ansGiven = document.getElementById("ansGiven" + questionIndex).value;
    console.log(ans );
    console.log(ansGiven);

    if (ansGiven === ans) {
        document.getElementById("ansRes" + questionIndex).innerHTML = "Correct!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ansRes" + questionIndex).innerHTML = "Try Again.";
    }

    ansGiven = "";
}
```